# Hamiltonian symmetry Lie algebra

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, hamiltonian, lie-algebra, observables

What is the connection between *complete set of commuting observables* and generators of the Lie group?

I have a Hamiltonian written down in second quantized formalism and I also checked that it commutes with the generators of the Lie group - $SU(3)$. How would I construct algebraically eigenstates of this Hamiltonian? How many quantum numbers do I need?

Is there any procedure to determine full symmetry of the Hamiltonian? Like in hydrogen atom, it is not $SO(3)$ but $SO(4)$.

Comment: Which Hamiltonian?

Answer (score 0):

If the Hamiltonian has $SU(2)$ symmetry then the Hilbert space can be spanned by eigenstates of *Cartan subalgebra* (one dimensional) operator and *Casimir operator*. As we know from elementary quantum mechanics

$$\begin{align}
\hat{L}^{2}\left|l,m \right\rangle &=l(l+1)\left|l,m \right\rangle,\\[3mm]
\hat{L}_{z}\left|l,m \right\rangle &= m\left|l,m \right\rangle,\\[3mm]
\left[\hat{L}^{2},  \hat{L}_{z}\right] &= 0.
\end{align}$$
So, we need two quantum numbers $l,m$.

$SU(3)$ group have two-dimensional Cartan subalgebra and two Casimir operators. Hilbert space can be spanned by eigenstates of Cartan subalgebra - two operators and one Casimir operator. In sum, $3$ quantum numbers are necessary.

Comment: This is incorrect.  States in $SU(3)$ are labelled by two weights (eigenvalues of the two Cartan elements) and two irrep labels since irreps in $SU(3)$ are labelled by two non-negative integers.  You might be able to get away with a single label or the dimension but this requires additional information, in particular in differentiating two irreps of the same dimension which are not equivalent (like $\mathbf{3}$ and $\mathbf{3}^*$).  In other words you need $4$ not $3$ labels in general.